# Ember: all actions handler?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to make catch *all* actions handler?

Problem is that `Ember.TargetActionSupport`'s `triggerAction` sent from a component does not bubble up.
So when I have nested components, when I send an action from child component, parent component catches it, but controller does not.

So I want to make an "action proxy" — parent component catches action and sends it's copy up. This method works but parent component has no idea of what actions will come from it's child so I need a "catch all" handler

Answer (score 0):

I've dig into ember source and found answer. This may be useful.

Component inherits from View. In fact, it is a simple View that acts as a controller for itself.
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-views/lib/views/component.js#L102

```
Ember.Component = Ember.View.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, Ember.ComponentTemplateDeprecation, {
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    set(this, 'context', this);
    set(this, 'controller', this);
  },
```

`set(this, 'controller', this)` makes Component isolated.
So to take advantage of Components binds and isolated self-control but to keep it transparent for actions, you should use Views with self-context:

```
App.MyTransparentComponent = Ember.View.extend
    init: ->
        @_super()
        @set('context', @)
```

In fact, you can make a Mixin with all code of Component, but with this init code and be happy with this cool stuf :)